# What are the official mirrors of the Maven Central Repository?

Tags: maven-2

Does anyone know if a list of known (and working) Maven Central Repository (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) mirrors?

If not, what mirrors do you use when the central repository is down?

Answer (score 23):

This is taken from @rvxnet's answer and an example of why link-only answer are not desirable. I've taken this from the [2015-05-20 WaybackMachine version of their link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150520185622/https://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Mirrors+Repositories):

Official, but not browseable:

- https://repo1.maven.org/maven2

Others:

- https://maven.antelink.com/content/repositories/central/

Also, there are [official instructions for configuring to use mirrors](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html). Essentially, you add to you `settings.xml` the something like the following:

```
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>planetmirror.com</id>
        <name>PlanetMirror Australia</name>
        <url>http://downloads.planetmirror.com/pub/maven2</url>
        <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

Comment: Worth noting some of these links now require https.

Comment: updated links and removed seemingly dead ones, if people know of more please add them

Answer (score 17):

I just found this:

```
<mirrors>
  <mirror>
   <id>google-maven-central</id>
   <name>Google Maven Central</name>
   <url>https://maven-central.storage.googleapis.com/maven2/</url>
   <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
  </mirror> 
</mirrors>
```

That worked great for me

credit: [Failed to get the server archetype by maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42288299/failed-to-get-the-server-archetype-by-maven)

Comment: This got me the jetbrains.annotations group, which I couldn't get without a mirror in place. I don't get it, but I'm glad this worked.

Comment: Thanks. This one is HTTPS which also solves few other problems. Thanks for this complete reply.

Comment: This gives `peer not authenticated` exception.. any hints?

Comment: this had dependencies i couldn't resolve anywhere else +10 saved my day

Answer (score 6):

*From [Using Mirrors for Repositories](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html):*

---

The official Maven 2 repository is at:

- http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 hosted in the US, or
- http://uk.maven.org/maven2 hosted in the UK.

A list of known mirrors is available in the [Repository Metadata](http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.meta/repository-metadata.xml). These mirrors **may not have the same contents and we don't support them in any way**.

---

*Also:*

---

The size of the central repository is increasing steadily. To save us bandwidth and you time, **mirroring the entire central repository is not allowed** (doing so will get you automatically banned). Instead, we suggest you setup a [repository manager](https://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html) as a proxy.

Answer (score 4):

Here https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.meta/repository-metadata.xml you can see the following list:

```
<mirrors>
    <!--mirror> 
        <id>cica.es</id>
        <url>http://ftp.cica.es/mirrors/maven2</url>
    </mirror-->
    <mirror>
        <id>repo.exist.com</id>
        <url>http://repo.exist.com/maven2</url>
    </mirror>
    <mirror>
        <id>ibiblio.org</id>
        <url>http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2</url>
    </mirror>
    <mirror>
        <id>ibiblio.net</id>
        <url>http://www.ibiblio.net/pub/packages/maven2</url>
    </mirror>
    <!--mirror>
        <id>mirror.netcologne.de</id>
        <url>http://mirror.netcologne.de/maven2</url> 
    </mirror -->
    <mirror>
        <id>uk.maven.org</id>
        <url>http://uk.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

Comment: getting error "'mirrors.mirror.mirrorOf' for repo.exist.com is missing @ \.m2\settings.xml"

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me!

```
<mirror>
  <id>central-secure</id>
  <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
  <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
```