# Failed to get the server archetype by maven

Tags: java, maven, teamcity

According to instruction from [Teamcity doc](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Getting+Started+with+Plugin+Development)

I use `mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeRepository=http://download.jetbrains.com/teamcity-repository -DarchetypeArtifactId=teamcity-server-plugin -DarchetypeGroupId=org.jetbrains.teamcity.archetypes -DarchetypeVersion=RELEASE` to create a project template of server-side-only plugin.

However, the error throws like below everytime I execute the mvn command.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0:generate (default-cli) > generate-source
s @ standalone-pom >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0:generate (default-cli) < generate-source
s @ standalone-pom <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0:generate (default-cli) @ standalone-pom
---
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/1.8
.3/groovy-1.8.3.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 20:12 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-02-17T10:16:15+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/21M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3
.0.0:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Execution default-cli of
goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0:generate failed: Plug
in org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0 or one of its dependenc
ies could not be resolved: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.groovy:groov
y:jar:1.8.3 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): GET request
of: org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/1.8.3/groovy-1.8.3.jar from central failed: Prema
ture end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 5522507; received:
3244032 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResoluti
onException
```

Anyone knows how to fix the issue?

Comment: You have some kind of internet/proxy problem on your end. It run normally here.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Thanks Jorge, the downloading process is not stopped immediately but can download halfway. Besides that, I have set the proxy in .m2 folder.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Could you please tell me the Maven version used by you? Thanks

Comment: I tested it on 3.2.5, 3.3.3 and also on 3.2.9 all worked

Comment: Thanks Jorge. There seems no relationship with the maven version. I will double check the network settings. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the mirrors in setttings.xml will fix the problem

```
<mirrors>
  <mirror>
    <id>google-maven-central</id>
    <name>Google Maven Central</name>
    <url>https://maven-central.storage.googleapis.com/maven2/</url>
    <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
  </mirror> 
</mirrors>
```

Please put above section in settings.xml

Comment: this worked for me, thank you.  would be interested in understanding why this is required to work. and how it solved the "[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.0:generate"